# Freeze White screen after update app in Play Store in lollipop 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a small/big problem with my Android app. All have been works fine until I did an update of the app. The update was changes in some screens, and added images. No changes in libraries, no changes in gradle, no changes in manifest (only added new activities)

We've noticed that some users in version 5.0 and 5.0.1 can't run the app. They told that the app is freeze in a white screen.  I can't show any log because I can't replicate the error. I've downloaded the version in the emulator in Android Studio and all works fine.

Someone know why could be the error??

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.base.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:largeHeap="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".app.ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".app.ui.paypal.PaypalActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".app.ui.comments.CommentsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".app.fcm.NotificationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_NOTIFICATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".app.ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".app.ui.base.WebViewActivity" android:noHistory="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.settings.SettingsUserAccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.login.SocialLoginActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.ads.VideoAdsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.categories.CategoriesActivity" android:noHistory="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.Games.SelectorActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.trivial.TrivialGameActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.apeFly.Start" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.friends.FriendsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.screen.MonkeyScreenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.campaign.CampaignDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.brand.BrandProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.fragments.CarritoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.RechargeListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.ResumeRechargeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.CodeRechargeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.SendApesToFriendActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.ResumeSendCreditFriendsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.BankAccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.ResumeBankAccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.favourites.FavouriteActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.recharge.ResumeRechargeMBActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.fragments.UserFragment" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.companies.CompaniesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.login.LoginMainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".app.ui.login.LoginCodeActivity"/>

        <service
            android:name=".app.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <service
            android:name=".app.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".app.geofencing.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".app.geofencing.GeofenceBootReceiver"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".app.receivers.SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="5d52eb34acc56c5050bc989bbe7acad1df1c0ab0" />

        <activity android:name="com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyInterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>

        <activity android:name="com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyAdViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

GRADLE:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}

android {

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 67
        versionName "3.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //ANDROID LIBRARIES
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    //GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    //PLAY SERVICES
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

    // RETROFIT
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.4'


    //IMAGES
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //FIREBASE
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

    //PAYPAL
    implementation('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.1') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }

    //EVENTBUS
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

    /* OTHERS */
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Network
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:0.12.3'

    //FABRIC
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    //AMPLITUDE
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.16.0'

    //FACEBOOK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'


    /* ButterKnife */
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    /*CIRCLE INDICATOR*/
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'

    /*AD COLONY*/
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.3.5.1'

    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.3"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.7.3"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0'

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2"

    // Espresso UI Testing dependencies.
    implementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2"
    androidTestImplementation  'com.21buttons:fragment-test-rule:1.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

UPDATE:

I've found the solution. Was a problem from facebook sdk. You need to update to last version 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'

Comment: don't build with SDK 27, as it is too high.  There are a lot features in API 24 and below have been deprecated.

Comment: What do you mean?? The app was working fine in SDK 27 all this time.

Comment: No, I mean some features of API 27 are not supported in lower API

Comment: ah, ok. You think that some feature could be the freeze white screen at startup. Do you know some way to force android to show the error, maybe in crashlytics?